# How to calculate cpu utilization in MHz?

Tags: python, linux, cpu

I am using the psutil module to get cpu utilization.

> psutil.cpu_percent()
>
> 7.2

which is in percentage.

But if I need it in MHz, is it possible?

Is there any tool in linux or python or any calculation to get the cpu utilization in MHz, or convert it from percentage to MHz?

Comment: That's not a duplicate (although this is a strange question).

Comment: The docs for `cpu_count` say 'Return the number of logical CPUs in the system'. It is not a percentage, it is a count. '4' means there are 4 CPUs. That will not change depending on utilisation.

Comment: Ah yes. There is an [oracle post](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-admin/script-clockrate-1980818.html) with a python script with a solution to this.

Comment: Note that Mhz are used to measure **clock speed**, and the relationship between clock speed and actual CPU utilization is fuzzy at best (totally unrelated at worst)

Comment: @goncalopp I was presuming they just had one of those systems where the cpu speed dynamically scales. If you look at their question history, it looks like this is what they wants.

Comment: @will I assumed so as well. It's just that you can probably have 0-10% utilization at the lowest clock speed, and 50-100% at the highest, even with a ondemand governor. You can also have 100% utilization in the lowest clock speed, if you use a aggressive powersave governor. Mhz just measures clock speed - whether it is related to actual CPU usage is dependent on a lot of external factors

Comment: Sorry Joe. Edited. with cpu_percent()

Comment: @goncalopp yah i know - but this only matters if you presume they want to use the clock speed to infer load. If they just want the current clock speed for some other use, then it doesn't matter.

Comment: @niladrichakrabarty what do you actually want to do? i.e. what will be the end product of your program / this piece of code?

Comment: Maybe just post an answer with "No, CPU utilization cannot meaningfully be expressed in MHz.  If you know your processor speed and utilization percentage, you get a number if you multiply them, but its usefulness is very limited."

Comment: Hi @will I have read the oracle post, but didn't find it quite efficient. 

The end result I need for my work is the cpu utilization and I got this idea of getting it in MHz after reading this : 

https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.monitoring.doc%2FGUID-FBA3A58A-EEC9-4B4D-8515-ECCF51188913.html

But I am not sure how are they doing it? 
Is it some one-to-one mapping with clock frequency e.g., if my max speed is 3100 Mhz, then 10% of cpu utilization is 310 Mhz.

Can anyone please confirm?

Comment: Just use the percentage. Providing the answer in MHz will be misleading.